# Deserialize object property with StringReader vs XmlNodeReader

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xsd, xmlserializer

Why does `XmlSerializer` populate my object property with an `XmlNode` array when deserializing an empty typed element using `XmlNodeReader` instead of an empty string like it does when using `StringReader` (or `XmlTextReader`)?

The second assertion in the following code sample fails:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(new StringReader(@"
    <Test xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance""
          xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"">
      <Value xsi:type=""xsd:string"" />
    </Test>"));
var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof (Test));

var reader1 = new StringReader(doc.InnerXml);
var obj1 = (Test) ser.Deserialize(reader1);
Debug.Assert(obj1.Value is string);

var reader2 = new XmlNodeReader(doc.FirstChild);
var obj2 = (Test) ser.Deserialize(reader2);
Debug.Assert(obj2.Value is string);

public class Test
{
    public object Value { get; set; }
}
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with the null internal `NamespaceManager` property but I'm not sure how to work around this mysterious limitation. How can I reliably deserialize a subset of my parsed XML document without converting it back into a string and re-parsing?

Comment: It looks like you are passing a partial document to the XmlSerializer in the second instance, and the entire document in the first instance, how do you expect it to reconstruct the type from a partial document?

Comment: By the way, if you debug and see what type obj2 is, its of class "Test" but the serializer has deserialized your obj2.Value object to an XmlNode, not a string. Its an interesting side-effect of not passing in the entire document to the serializer.

Comment: The FirstChild of an XmlDocument is the whole document (doc.FirstChild == doc.DocumentElement). So both readers have the same information, just in different forms (XML string vs parsed XmlNode graph).

Comment: Try this: `Console.WriteLine(doc.FirstChild.ParentNode == null)`, prints false. The `FirstChild` has a parent node, which is the document.

Comment: If you change the Value property type to string and change the Value element in the XML to `<Value>Hello</Value>` then both readers work just fine. Deserializing from an XML fragment (partial document) is exactly what XmlNodeReader is for. It just doesn't appear to recognize the xsi:type attribute for some reason.

Comment: It works if you change `Value` to a string as well in the `Test` class, I guess it just can't cast.

Comment: Maybe a bug.  If I use Linq to XML and do `var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml); var reader3 = xdoc.Root.CreateReader(); var obj3 = (Test)ser.Deserialize(reader3);` I get a string.  Can you switch to the new API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this is a very old `XmlNodeReader` bug that [Microsoft have no intention of fixing](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/772329/xmlserializer-xsi-type-attributes-with-namespaces-dont-deserialize-correctly-with-xmlnodereader).  (Archived Microsoft Connect link [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20131201040931/https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/772329/xmlserializer-xsi-type-attributes-with-namespaces-dont-deserialize-correctly-with-xmlnodereader)). I found a workaround on Lev Gimelfarb's blog [here](http://coderstuff.blogspot.com.au/2005/10/xmlserializer-bug-when-xsitype-is-used.html) that adds namespaces to the reader's `NameTable` as prefixes are looked up.

```
public class ProperXmlNodeReader : XmlNodeReader
{
    public ProperXmlNodeReader(XmlNode node) : base(node)
    {
    }

    public override string LookupNamespace(string prefix)
    {
        return NameTable.Add(base.LookupNamespace(prefix));
    }
}
```